# Skype API Converting FullName to Handle?

Tags: c#, api, skype4com

I am creating an application to send a mass message. The users are being loaded into a listbox. I am loading it into a listbox so I can choose who to and who not to send messages to. Here is what I have.

```
        foreach (User user in axSkype1.Friends)
        {
            foreach (String friends in listBox1.SelectedItems)
            {
                if (richTextBox2.Text.Contains("{username}"))
                {
                    axSkype1.SendMessage(friends, richTextBox2.Text.Replace("{username}", "") + user.FullName + " " + "\n\n" + "" + flatTextBox1.Text + "\n\n" + richTextBox1.Text);
                }
                else
                {
                    axSkype1.SendMessage(friends, richTextBox2.Text + "\n\n" + flatTextBox1.Text + "\n\n" + richTextBox1.Text);
                }
            }
        }
```

The part where it says user.FullName is what I am having trouble with. When it sends the message it send the message to the person selected but it sends it for how ever many contacts I have. I just want it to send one but with the users FullName.

Comment: It does not look like you are exiting the loop.

Comment: Its not that, I can get it to send the user's skypeID but I would much rather it send the user's  fullname. That's why I need to convert the user's handle to a full name.

Comment: Why don't you match the selected item against the user's full name instead? You have the user object, so you can just get `.Handle` simply. I.e `if(friends == user.FullName)`.